# Get the text from a web page

Tags: visual-studio-2008, capture, text-capture

How do I capture the text from the web page?
Do I need to get the page source and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can get web page's content and save it into the string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebClient` object has a method available to do this for you:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: The example above works only in older versions, not my Visual Studio 2008. The correct code is:
    #using <System.dll>
    using namespace System::Net;
    using namespace System::IO;
    using namespace System;
    ...
    void main(){
        WebClient^ client = gcnew WebClient;
        CString html = client->DownloadString(_T("http://www.google.bg/"));
    }