# Handling URL in c#

Tags: c#, windows, url

I am making a windows form application using c# that will check a url, follow redirection and sees if the redirected url is the one i want.

As a new programmer, I have only handled any network related things in java and my searches of doing the same in c# have been unsuccessful. Could you guys help me out please?

Comment: You want to use 2 completely and opposite programming languages to do something C# could handle by itself? doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: no what I mean is I only have experience in java so I was wondering how i could achieve the objective in c#

Comment: Start by using the search on this site, there is plenty of questions that show how to get a page and how to check the page content, more specially you want either webclient/webrequest and htmlagilitypack library. [**Learn how to get the page then how to check the content to see if its what you need.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable)

Comment: thanks:) I will check those out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
WebClient wc= new WebClient();
var str = wc.DownloadString("YourURL");
```

With `WebClient` you can send request and get response.