# How can I compare text from two different web pages and compare it?

Tags: c#, string, compare, html

I want to write a code in C#

1. Go to www.abc.com > read the whole text available on the page > save the text to string1 
   then
2. Go to www.xyz.com > read the whole text available on the page > save the text to string2 
   then
3. Compare string1 with string2 to verify they are same

eg.

if `string1 = "Hello World"` and `string2 = "Hello World"` > test passes

if `string1 = "Hello World"` and `string2 = "Hello Tom"` > test fails

Comment: Great. Open up a compiler and start coding. If you encounter problems, feel free to ask for help here. If you need someone to code this for you, look at a site that rents coders.

Comment: "read the whole text available on the page" means the complete HTML page or it should only compare the content in the body and ignore HTML tags?

Comment: read the whole text available on the page including tags, thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a blatant request for code with no demonstrated attempt at solving the problem at hand.

Comment: start off by learning how to download a web page in c# - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always nice to post code snippets, so it proves us that you actually tried something. But there you go, it's a pretty simple task...

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isEqual = DownloadString("www.abc.com") == DownloadString("www.xyz.com")
        // do whatever you want with it
    }    

    private static string DownloadString(string address)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            return client.DownloadString(address);
        }
    }
}
```