# I need to get data from a Website and save it to string

Tags: c#, regex

```
<td class="lineitem">964.00 oz</td>
<td class="lineitem" align="right" bgcolor="#141414"><font color="#33ff66">230.00</td>
<td class="lineitem" align="right">$460</td>      
<td class="lineitem" align="right">1.00</td>
<td class="lineitem" align="right">$2.00</td>
```

From this I am trying to get: 964.00 , 230.00 , 460 , 1.00 , 2.00
and save them to string to use later on

Thanks in advance

I have tried :

```
string bleh = ("http://www.drugrunners.net/quickBuySummary.cfm?");
string[] qual = Regex.Split(bleh, "<td class=");
      for (int i = 1; i < qual.Length; i++)
         {
          switch (i)
      {
        case 1:
            Details[0] =  Regex.Split(qual[i], "\">")[0];
               button3.Text = Regex.Split(qual[i], "\">")[1]
         break;
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Did you run into any specific problems with your approach?

Comment: Edited to show what i tried also no problem in my approach, just not showing what i want

Answer (score 1):

what you  need is a web scraping tool like `HtmlAgilityPack`
here an example

```
     HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
     doc.Load("http://yourUrl")
    var findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").Where(d => 
    d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Contains("lineitem")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^<td class=\"lineitem\".*>(?<number>.*)</td>$")
```

Will capture 964.00 oz, 230.00, $460, 1.00 and $2.00 respectively, from the lines you posted.

It does require you to run one row at a time, and you will have to figure out what to do with your units as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the remote webpage and 'scrape' it using a library like html agility pack:

About retrieving it, this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable) is useful:

```
protected void getHtml(string url){
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string downloadString = client.DownloadString(url);
    return downloadString;
}
```

Then once you create a html document out of the string (not sure about how to do it, but should be a no brainer), you can parse it using [html agility pack and XPATH](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples);

Ultimately, I think you can get what you want by following [this CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H), and you'd get something like this:

```
protected void ClickMeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    var document = getHtml("http://url.to.your/page");
    var tdTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td"); //use a xpath expression to select contents
    int counter = 1;
    if (aTags != null)
    {
        foreach (var aTag in aTags){
        myVarToSave = tdTag.InnerHtml ;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern can be `>\$?([\d\.]+).*<`

Meaning:

- searching something between > and <
- \$? is the optional $
- () indicate a subpattern to match, returned as $matches[1]
- [] indicate the characters to match, the + incidates one or more
- \d is a digit
- \. is a dot
- .* is anything following

In php,

```
preg_match_all(
   '@>\\$*([\\d\\.]+)<@', 
   '<td class="lineitem">964.00 oz</td>
    <td class="lineitem" align="right" bgcolor="#141414"><font color="#33ff66">230.00</td>
    <td class="lineitem" align="right">$460</td>      
    <td class="lineitem" align="right">1.00</td>
    <td class="lineitem" align="right">$2.00</td>', 
   $matches
);
```

returns

```
$matches => array (
  0 => array (
    0 => '>964.00 oz<',
    1 => '>230.00<',
    2 => '>$460<',
    3 => '>1.00<',
    4 => '>$2.00<',
  ),
  1 => array (
    0 => '964.00',
    1 => '230.00',
    2 => '460',
    3 => '1.00',
    4 => '2.00',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is, does what you're doing (in your example) work? Your `string bleh` line tells me otherwise. You're obviously working with a page that needs authentication, so you can't simply access the document on HtmlDocument.Load. It will be a little harder than doing any of these answers before you can scrape the page. You will need to figure out:

1. How to do a proper HttpRequest
2. How to request with authentication (cookies/postdata, whatever it involves).
3. How to get the response of the page you want and parse it with HtmlAgilityPack

You can look for each of these points separately on S.O. or elsewhere.

You can also take the other path and download the page manually if it works for you, and then you can do a IO.File method to open the document, which you can feed to HtmlDocument.LoadHtml(), meaning you can skip to number 3.