# how to fix counting the most frequent words in a website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have program that getting url from the user, and searching in the website for the words that most common.

```
    public void url_input_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string StringFromTheInput = TextBox1.Text;
    var request_ = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(StringFromTheInput);
    WebResponse response = request_.GetResponse();
    Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
    string content = String.Empty;

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            content= client.DownloadString(StringFromTheInput);

        }

    WordCount(content);


}

public static Dictionary<string, int> WordCount(string content, int numWords = int.MaxValue)
{
    var delimiterChars = new char[] { ' ', ',', ':', '\t', '\"', '\r', '{', '}', '[', ']', '=', '/' };
    return content
        .Split(delimiterChars)
        .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
        .Select(x => x.ToLower())
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { Word = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .Take(numWords)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Word, x => x.Count);
}
```

The issue is that what I have in "content" in the end of the function. 
[image: https://imgur.com/a/Q0gdjdM]
why it skip the linq line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the solution and it works ok. I did try the http://google.com URL.

The debugger is not skipping the LINQ line , it executes it and then returns by moving to the end of the method.

I would suggest to add the return result to a variable and add a break point on the last parenthesis.

```
        var result = WordCount(content); 
    } // put a break point here
```

Comment: Thanks. the problem now it gives me the html of the website not the content itself

Comment: Ok, no problem. I believe the HTML is the content of the website. If my answer has helped please accept it.

Comment: I will. I meant that if the url is for article I want the most common words in the article. not the html of the page. do you know how to change it? thanks

Comment: That i how you get the content. Check this post it explains how to extract the content. It uses the same approach  you did . :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510212/how-i-can-get-web-pages-content-and-save-it-into-the-string-variable

Comment: What you can do is , once you retrieve the content is extract the part that you are interested in and then execute the method WordCount()

Comment: its a problem because how can I now that every content is it the same place

Comment: I have provided you with an answer to your other question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900719/copying-text-of-website-using-webbrowser-failed/53902762#53902762 . Hope you appreciate the effort.

Comment: really appreciate!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please remember to  accept the answer if they have helped. It show appreciation for someone else effort. Thanks

Comment: Sure I will!working about the solution. can I print in `PrintNode` the most common words with my linq expression ? thanks

Comment: If the comment is about the other question , please ask it there.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if they have helped, so we can concentrate on the other question. Thank you