# Copying website text using WebBrowser failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to copy the text of a website(getting the URL from the user) using the `WebBrowser` class but it seems that none of the thread lines are running. I also tried using `WebBrowser` without the thread but it didn't work. Any advice will be welcome. It's my first time with these libraries so many thanks for helping me get what I want.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
{
    var th = new Thread(() => {
        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        br.Navigate(url);
        global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
        object n = new object();
        br.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll",true,n);
        br.Document.ExecCommand("Copy",true,n);
        string text = Clipboard.GetText();
        MessageBox.Show(text, "Text");
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (br.Url == e.Url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
      // global::System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
    }
}


public void url_input_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string StringFromTheInput = TextBox1.Text;
    System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(StringFromTheInput);
    runBrowserThread(uri);
}

public static Dictionary<string, int> WordCount(string content, int numWords = int.MaxValue)
{
    var delimiterChars = new char[] { ' ', ',', ':', '\t', '\"', '\r', '{', '}', '[', ']', '=', '/' };
    return content
        .Split(delimiterChars)
        .Where(x => x.Length > 0)
        .Select(x => x.ToLower())
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { Word = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .Take(numWords)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Word, x => x.Count);
}
}
```

Comment: Any logic after `br.Navigate(url);` should be in the event handler.

Comment: @Crowcoder what do you mean? thanks

Comment: I'll try to elaborate.. any code after `br.Navigate(url)` that accesses the document (like `ExecCommand`) should be in the `browser_DocumentCompleted` method because you can't do anything with the document until it has been loaded.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks, I fixed it. but the lines after `browser_DocumentCompleted` not runing at all. why?

Comment: I don't know, but usually you would reference the web browser control that you dropped on the form instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Apologies, I just noticed you were doing this on a web form. Why? the web browser control is a winforms control, you should have no need for it in a webforms application.

Comment: @Crowcoder thank you very much. this way you recommend about fetching data from website? I need to parse the website data for specific words and not finding way to do it with c#\ASP.net Thanks!

Comment: @Crowcoder mm not because a smart reason, I tried this, and didn't know about  web browser before

Comment: I might suggest looking at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks. But I see now it returns the HTML of the website. but it I have article in the website I want the article itself.

Comment: @Crowcoder If you know about it I will very want to know. many thanks!

Comment: You may have to parse the html to extract the article. But, many sites provide API's. You might be able to request the article and nothing more. I don't know what site you are contacting or if they have an API.

Comment: @Crowcoder that is my big problem. I am requesting from the user to provide a url. so I need to parse any kind of website he gives me if its article/ news website. what I need is to bring the most common word / less common word. (I gave the article for the example) any advice for me? many thanks!

Comment: If you accept any URL a user may give you, this could be challenging. HTML5 defines an <article> tag, so you could extract based on that but you can't really count on it being implemented by any random site.

Comment: @Crowcoder lets say I will based on that(<article>). what is the best way to extract the data I want? many thanks.

Comment: [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) is a library for parsing html. I dont' have much experience with it myself but check out its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments - How to extract the actual content from an HTML from a page.

**Edit**

After discussing the issue with Israel Nehes it appears that the solution was to retrieve particular tags values.

I have updated the code, hopefully this will help.

Retrieve the HTML,then using XPath Path Expressions you can retrieve the node that you are interested in which would be the

and  tags

```
   static public StringBuilder Content { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string html;
        Content = new StringBuilder();
        string url = @"https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/uknews/universal-credit-forcing-families-to-wait-months-for-help-to-pay-childcare-bills-mps-warn/ar-BBRjFtR?li=BBoPRmx";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

        html = wc.DownloadString(url);
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var allP = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
        var allLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
        foreach (var p in allP)
        {
            var outerHtml = p.OuterHtml;
            List<string> potentialContent = Regex.Replace(outerHtml, "<[^>]*>", "").Split(' ').ToList();

            if (potentialContent.Count > 1)
            {
                Content.Append(new StringBuilder(string.Join(" ", potentialContent)));
            }
        }

        foreach (var p in allLink)
        {
            var outerHtml = p.OuterHtml;
            List<string> potentialContent = Regex.Replace(outerHtml, "<[^>]*>", "").Split(' ').ToList();

            if (potentialContent.Count > 1)
            {
                Content.Append(new StringBuilder(string.Join(" ", potentialContent)));
            }
        }
    }
```

The property Content will contain the tags values.

Comment: Thank you so much! checking it! hope to solve it this way.  can I print in `PrintNode` the most common words with my linq expression ? this is what I need in the end

Comment: and I have the expression, the thing is the printing methods here not returning similar varible

Comment: what's the  URL ?

Comment: Ok I see what the problem is. Declare commonWordsCount  as a global variable and it should give you a result.

Comment: Declare commonWordsCount  as a property and it should give you a result.  public Dictionary<string, int> CommonWordsCount { get; set; }

Comment: I have created a console application as stated above. Does it work though ?

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if they have helped.

Comment: I will try. thanks! and I used it first with ASP.Net the form application. and it really crashed. should I use console and asking for entering the url

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. Why does it crash, whats the exception? BTW thanks for accepting it. What are your requirements? Does it specify what solutions you must use? Is this an assignment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185720/discussion-between-alex-leo-and-israel-nehes).