# Mimicking Fiddler's Compose->Raw feature in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, https, httpwebrequest

I'm looking for the *simplest* way to send a **raw** http string over the internet. I don't want to fiddle with header or cookie or contents properties, with methods and all the "nice" things there is. I want it to be just like Fiddler is:

[image]

You write your whole string on a textbox (1) and then click "Execute" (2). And you're done = PROFIT.

**I just want to type some text, and have it sent. Nothing more, nothing less.**

The `Socket` class would be awesome if it didn't fail to send my messages to HTTPS servers, which is something that Fiddler, for instance, has no problem accomplishing.

Comment: You could always make an extension method.

Comment: I was just wondering if there's a direct method. The idea is precisely to not have to write that extension method :(

Comment: You know that you'd only have to write it once in your entire career, and you could reuse it forever after. :)

Comment: I could just as well never have to write it in the first place if there's already a method that does it.

Comment: Yes, if it existed, you wouldn't have to write it.  Quick way to check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest_methods.aspx

Comment: You might like the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) class better.

Comment: But `HttpWebRequest` doesn't have a `Request` property. What exactly are you trying to do? Or avoid doing?

Comment: The given code is what I was expecting to find, not what actually exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to read from a URL into a string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048199/easiest-way-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-string-in-net)

Comment: That has *nothing* to do with the supposed duplicate. I'm asking how to send an HTTP request over a HTTPS connection without having to manually set every header.

Comment: What headers do you think you'll need to set? The standard headers are set when you create an `HttpWebRequest`. If there's something specific that your server needs and that `HttpWebRequest` doesn't supply, then of course you'll have to set it yourself.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: When using Fiddler, I can go to the "Composer"->"Raw" and then write whatever I want there and click "execute". I'm looking for exactly the same functionality in C#. I don't want to have to manually fiddle with properties and methods, I just want to send the full http request as a string and to be done with it.

Comment: That functionality doesn't exist in `HttpWebRequest` or any other Framework class that I'm aware of. You'll have to write a wrapper method or find one that somebody else has written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of hassle, here's how it's done:

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostName, port);
var stream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(), false, (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true, null); //little hack
stream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName);
//from now on you may write your usual stuff on the stream
```

Yes, it's that easy.

There are more examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever try using [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Example from:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
        }
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();

        // Add a user agent header in case the  
        // requested URI contains a query.

        client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        Stream data = client.OpenRead (args[0]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        Console.WriteLine (s);
        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
```

Comment: I don't to have to set the headers manually. I just want to type in the whole text and then have it sent. See the edited post above.

Answer (score 1):

You get a good control over the request/response routine using the [System.Net.Http.HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), if that's an option for you (.NET 4.5):

```
string url = "https://site.com";
using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
  var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
  var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
  ...
```

**Edit:**

> ... settings the fields one by one ....

Look at the [HttpClient Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944845%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for helpers that could aid you in "setting the fields one by one"

Comment: At first it seemed to solve my issue, but it really doesn't. Look at the edited post above.