# URL Formats are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reading File with File.OpenRead method, I am giving this path

```
   http://localhost:10001/MyFiles/folder/abc.png
```

I have tried this as well but no luck

```
http://localhost:10001//MyFiles//abc.png
```

but its giving

> *URL Formats are not supported*

When I give physical path of my Drive like this,It works fine
d:\MyFolder\MyProject\MyFiles\folder\abc.png

How can I give file path to an Http path?

this is my code

```
public FileStream GetFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename);
    return file;
}
```

Comment: This might be your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048199/easiest-way-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-string-in-net

Comment: use Server.MapPath("//MyFiles")+"//abc.png" as filename

Comment: you need to use  Server.MapPath() as file operation required physical file path not virtual path. in your case you should use string filePath=Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/folder/abc.png");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use a WebClient as suggested in other answers or fetch the relative path like this:

```
var url = "http://localhost:10001/MyFiles/folder/abc.png";

var uri = new Uri(url);
var path = Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);

var file = GetFile(path);
// ...
```

In general you should get rid of the absolute URLs.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at `WebClient` ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)), it has many utility methods for downloading data from the web.

If you want the resource as a `Stream`, try:

```
using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    using(Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(uriString))
    {
        using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to download the HTML is by using the WebClient class. You do this like:

```
    private string GetWebsiteHtml(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        stream.Dispose();
        reader.Dispose();
        return result;
    }
```

Then, If you want to further process the HTML to ex. extract images or links, you will want to use technique known as HTML scrapping.

It's currently best achieved by using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Also, documentation on WebClient class: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048199/easiest-way-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-string-in-net) I found this snippet. Might do exactly what you need:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   string s = client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://.../abc.png"), filename);
}
```

It uses the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a file:// URL to a UNC file name, you should use the `Uri.LocalPath` property, [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.localpath?view=net-5.0).

In other words, you can do this:

```
public FileStream GetFile(string url)
{
    var filename = new Uri(url).LocalPath;
    FileStream file = File.OpenRead(filename);
    return file;
}
```