# Creating a file stream for a HTTP file

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I need to create a file stream directly at a server location using an URL. Something like

```
fs = new FileStream("http://SiteName.in/abc/xyz/pqr.pdf", FileMode.Create);
```

but its giving me this exception:

> URI formats are not supported

I tried it with many other options but not providing satisfactory result.

Comment: Do you want to read from or write to the stream?

Comment: I think they want to upload a file to a server, given the FileMode.Create

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Formats are not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918433/url-formats-are-not-supported)

Comment: i need to create and write directly at specified location. when we work with fs = new FileStream("c:\\pqr.pdf", FileMode.Create) it works but doesn't work by providing URL m serching correct way to do so..

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a *file* stream of a HTTP request. That is not how the class and the web works.

Use [`WebClient.OpenWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t27yce3(v=vs.110).aspx)  or the direct [`WebClient.UploadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using (Stream s = wc.OpenWrite("url"))
{
    ...
}
```

Of course, your server should support the POST request though. You can also use the more manual [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: You can use request|response streams.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Indeed. Or `OpenWrite`, which might be better than `UploadString` if you need a `Stream` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download your file into `Stream`

```
public static Stream DownloadFile(string TargetFile)
{
    WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
    byte[] BytesFile = MyWebClient.DownloadData(TargetFile);

    MemoryStream iStream = new MemoryStream(BytesFile);

    return iStream;
}
```