# Using url in C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, url, urlrequest

This code is written with python:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "http://www.example.com/"
req = http.request('GET', url)
source = req.dat
```

I want to know how can I write it with C#.

Comment: What is this code suppose to do?

Comment: assign http://www.example.com/ url's html or xml source to a string valuable. @MaxMommersteeg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to read from a URL into a string in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048199/easiest-way-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-string-in-net)

Comment: @BardiaHeydari Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just to *download from URL* you can try using

```
  String url = @"http://www.example.com/";
  Byte[] dat = null;

  // In case you need credentials for Proxy
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials))
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    // Seems that you need raw data, Byte[]; if you want String - wc.DownLoadString(url);
    dat = wc.DownloadData(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) // Use using, for automatic dispose of client
{
    //Get HTMLcode from page
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Add reference to `System.Net` at top of your class:

```
using System.Net;
```

But Oliver's answer offers more control :).

Comment: I like it!  Good for downloading to a `string`.

Comment: What if it needs username and password?

Comment: Then use: `if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials))
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;` , code by @Dmitry Bychenko, default credentials will be provided.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're downloading a web response.  Below is one way to do this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/");

using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
   var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
   var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But Max's answer is easier :).