# C# random Webrequest

Tags: c#, http, request

i have some skills in c#, but never worked with web request.

So my friend make an Site, and i wanna request this site like https://www.mysite.de/(md5hash). I overgive with the url an md5 hash, and on the website the md5 will checked, when its checked the webserver send me an true as answer, when the hash didnt checked i get an false.

like this:
string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");

can someone please help me? cant find an example like this.. is the way possible or do you know a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# how to properly make a http web GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108264/c-sharp-how-to-properly-make-a-http-web-get-request)

Comment: no not so right, so look this:             string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com"); can i make something like this?

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is not working? Are  you asking how to create an md5 hash?

Comment: No, so i try to explain it. i have an application, and an webserver with an homepage, when i enter in the application an key, the key will encrypt to md5. i wanna send a webrequest to my homepage with the md5 together, and the website check if the md5 is registred. when the md5 is registred the website answer me with true, when md5 isnt registred answer with false, you know what i mean? sorry for my englisch