# How do i access Iframe #document with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this frame i cannot access,from initial inspection of the frame i noticed the frame contained a #document then i wrote a code to access the frame.

```
$body = document.body;    
$body.children[3];    
$yo = $body.children[3];
$yo.children[0];    
$next = $yo.children[0];    
$next.children[3];    
$plus = $next.children[3];    
$plus.children[0];    
$star = $plus.children[0];    
$star.children[0];    
$staragain = $star.children[0];    
$staragain.children[1];    
$nextstar = $staragain.children[1];    
$nextstar.children[1];    
$afternext = $nextstar.children[1];    
$afternext.contentWindow;
```

The last line returns restricted,and
`iframe.contentDocument`returns `null`.
Then i tried to access the frame document which is a #document with`iframe.children[0]`it returned `undefined`,then i left the array open but nothing happened.All codes i run on the frame returns undefined how do i access this frame #document?[yoyoyo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0x7D.png).

Answer (score 3):

`iframe.contentWindow.document` but only if the origin is the same, because of [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: How do i set the origin if the origin is not the same?

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately we can't set the origin. If you need to access to document of other origin, there are two ways, perform an ajax GET/POST request only if server have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourDomine ( or *) https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin OR perform a GET/POST from server side

Comment: i know how to configure an XHR but i don't know how to access the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header...

Comment: it's a server side header, if you don't control the server or this header is not present, the only way is perform a GET/POST from server side, not a browser. If you control the server it depends of the server code, but it's really easy.

Comment: Example in php:  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: How do i know if this header is present?

Comment: Enter the page with the browser (if possible) open console (usually F12) search network and reload the page. look for the resource, for example index.html and look for response headers. Example: this site https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html has Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  header

Comment: It's not present.

Comment: Can i request for it?

Comment: The only way is GET/POST from server side

Comment: I run iis,How do i do this from the server side?

Comment: .net ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108264/c-sharp-how-to-properly-make-a-http-web-get-request

Comment: you have any idea how i can run those codes on iis?