# How to wait for all task includes task.factory

Tags: c#

```
private async Task StartRequesting()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
   {
      await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
      {
          string Result =  await GetAsync("www.google.com");
          Console.WriteLine(Result);
     });
   }
}

Console.WriteLine("Starting Request");

await StartRequesting();

Console.WriteLine("Requesting has been finished");
```

How can I now wait that all the Task has been finished?
I tryed Task.WhenAll but the Result is then like that

```
Starting Request
(google result)
(google result)
(google result)
Requesting has been finished
(google result)
(google result)
```

**Note**: I dont want use it without `Task.Factory.StartNew` because it takes then too long to done all the request.

Comment: 1. You should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. 2. There should be no need for it, as GetAsync is already async. Why wrap an I/O-bound task inside a CPU-bound task and wasting resources? 3. How have you done `Task.WhenAll`? It should be: `var tasks = new List<Task>(); for (int i=0; i<50; i++) { tasks.Add(GetAsync("www.google.com").ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(task.Result)); } await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`.

Comment: @ckuri testing rightt now will. giving you feedback some minutes

Comment: @ckuri well that works. but I need to create a new task when calling `await StartRequesting()` to prevent deadlock

Comment: What do you mean with thread-block?

Comment: I mean that the UI has some lags when I move the Form

Comment: okay weird I think I fixed that without using a new Task. I have another question. why should I use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew? I saw on some websites that these are same ?

Comment: This could be if your GetAsync method has lots of expensive non-async code before the first await in the method, as everything before the first await is executed on the calling thread.

Comment: [`StartNew` is a dangerous, low-level method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). `Task.Run` is a modern replacement for it.

Comment: @StephenCleary could you share your version how you would do it?

Comment: I would do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61532055/263693).

Comment: but the UI hangs try it out with a WinForm. anyway that one from @ckuri works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always find the cleanest way to do this is via LINQ, assuming there isn't a limit on concurrent requests:

```
private async Task StartRequesting()
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 50)
        .Select(async _ =>
        {
            string Result = await GetAsync("www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(Result);
        });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

No blocking occurs and no Tasks need to be manually created.

Comment: ok well thats nice. how can that be done if there is a  generic list instead of number?

Comment: I tested that but the UI is hanging when using this way

Comment: also adding a await Task.Delay() does nothing

Comment: its the same code from you. if you change the value from 50 to 250 you can see it ( I mean it dosn't matter if 50 or 5000 the ui hangs

Comment: Its the GetAsync function from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108442/13436341

Comment: Just realised your writing a console app which doesn't have a UI thread. `StartRequesting` will only return once all 50 HTTP requests have completed; this will take an amount of time, irrespective of whether the requests happen in serial or parallel.

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier, cleaner and more efficent to throw all the tasks into a list and get the results after everything is done.

```
 private async Task StartRequesting()
        {
            var taskList = new List<Task<string>>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                taskList.Add(Task.Run(async () => await GetAsync("www.google.com")));

            var tWhenAll = await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());

            foreach(var t in taskList)
                Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
        }
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code. 1. Don’t wrap I/O-bound tasks within CPU-bound tasks (if there is no good reason like heavy CPU-bound work). You are wasting 50 (!) threads here and threads are very expensive. 2. The `if` block is unnecessary and will never be called as `await` will automatically throw if an exception occurs. 3. Not an issue per se, but this code will print the results only when all tasks/requests have finished, whereas OP’s code prints the results as soon as they become available.

Comment: @ckuri, Per op 'How can I now wait that all the Task has been finished?' Also, 50 threads that run at 2 seconds a pop, compared to running each task 50 times at 2 seconds a pop is worth the "expensiveness" of a thread. But I changed my code, since my code = await anyways, it would do the same thing either way. Just cleaner the way you suggested.