# How to access REST API endpoints in a C# code

Tags: c#

I have set up a backend server with multiple endpoints using NodeJS with the ExpressJS framework. These REST Api Endpoints are connected to a Mongodb Database.

Due to project requirements, I had to write some code on C# that will also be calling and posting data into the database. However, I am now having trouble accessing the collections created by the ExpressJS Api Endpoint on my C# code.

May I know how is it normally done? Eg. how do I create a GET request from C# to access a collection created by ExpressJS Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly make a http web GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108264/how-to-properly-make-a-http-web-get-request)

Answer (score 0):

1. restful request is just a format of HTTP request. so you should send the request first.
2. then when you get restful response, you should deserialize it in JSON format.
3. show the example code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientSample
{
    public class Product
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void ShowProduct(Product product)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {product.Name}\tPrice: " +
                $"{product.Price}\tCategory: {product.Category}");
        }

        static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "api/products", product);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // return URI of the created resource.
            return response.Headers.Location;
        }

        static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
        {
            Product product = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            }
            return product;
        }

        static async Task<Product> UpdateProductAsync(Product product)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(
                $"api/products/{product.Id}", product);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Deserialize the updated product from the response body.
            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
            return product;
        }

        static async Task<HttpStatusCode> DeleteProductAsync(string id)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(
                $"api/products/{id}");
            return response.StatusCode;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            // Update port # in the following line.
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64195/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                // Create a new product
                Product product = new Product
                {
                    Name = "Gizmo",
                    Price = 100,
                    Category = "Widgets"
                };

                var url = await CreateProductAsync(product);
                Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");

                // Get the product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);

                // Update the product
                Console.WriteLine("Updating price...");
                product.Price = 80;
                await UpdateProductAsync(product);

                // Get the updated product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);

                // Delete the product
                var statusCode = await DeleteProductAsync(product.Id);
                Console.WriteLine($"Deleted (HTTP Status = {(int)statusCode})");

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

4. reference [call web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)