# http request from a site other than localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i need to get data from website address https://www."vgbg"/#getting-started (this example)
in dot net core 3.1 project

i try this

````
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddCommandLine(args)
          .Build();


            var hostUrl = configuration["hosturl"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostUrl))
                hostUrl = "https://www.balldontlie.io/#players";


            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls(hostUrl)  
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
```i dosnt work and i dont know where i write the request....
thanks
````

Comment: You can follow this document => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108264/how-to-properly-make-a-http-web-get-request

Comment: _"i dosnt work"_ Can you tell what you mean, do you get something like an error/exception or do you observe something you had not expected (what exactly)?

Comment: Do you want to know how to call the request in another project?