# C# HttpClient or HttpWebRequest class

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

currently in my projects I use the HttpWebRequest class to call any kind of REST APIs.

like this

```
    public string Post(string postData)
    {
        string resultString = string.Empty;

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(_serviceEndoint);

        HttpWebRequest httpWebReq = (HttpWebRequest)req;
        httpWebReq.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;

        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "Password");
        try
        {
            Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();

            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);

                    resultString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultString = ex.ToString();
        }

        return resultString;
    }
```

This is working :)
But I am curious about the rather new way of doing so.
Does the HttpClient class have any downsides (your experiences, opinions)?

Is using that class currently the 'better' way to call rest services (get,post, put, delete), instead of doing all the things manually ?

Comment: `HttpClient` is much simpler.

Comment: Any things I cant do, when prefering HttpClient over the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of `HttpClient` is that it is simpler, and supported on most Portable Class Library profiles. The disadvantage is that it doesn't support non-http requests, which `WebRequest` does. In other words `HttpClient` is a replacement for `HttpWebRequest` but there isn't afaik a replacement for `FtpWebRequest`, etc.

Also see this post for more details: [HttpClient vs HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214930/httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest)