# What is HttpClient's default maximum connections

Tags: c#, httpclient

Does HttpClient use the same ServicePoint Connection Limit as HttpWebRequest?

Thanks

Comment: See the comparison here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214930/httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses the same ServicePointManager so the answer is yes.

You can change the limit programmatically though if you want, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7af54za5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: In .NET 6, ServicePointManager is flagged as Obsolete.

Answer (score 25):

The answer is not complete. It depends on implementation.
In .net core [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_ServicePointManager_DefaultConnectionLimit) setting is not used, [HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netcore-2.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_MaxConnectionsPerServer) should be used instead.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timomta/2017/10/23/controlling-the-number-of-outgoing-connections-from-httpclient-net-core-or-full-framework/

Comment: When using DI, this is configured with: `services.AddHttpClient(clientName).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp => new HttpClientHandler() { MaxConnectionsPerServer = 2 });` Also note that `SocketsHttpHandler` is the newer implementation of `HttpMessageHandler` compared to `HttpClientHandler`, but you can still use `HttpClientHandler` as it seems to be more flexible and just forwards through to `SocketsHttpHandler` anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Since I couldn't find an official answer anywhere in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-6.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_MaxConnectionsPerServer), decompiling the code for .NET 6 yields a default value of `int.MaxValue` for  `HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer`.

This *should* also be true for any version of .NET Core.

```cs
namespace System.Net.Http
{
    internal static partial class HttpHandlerDefaults
    {
        public const int DefaultMaxConnectionsPerServer = int.MaxValue;
        ...
    }
}
```