# HttpClient gets stuck on async task

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a HttpClient and I'm pulling streams based on files on a remote server using the following code. When the thread gets to the third await, it pauses there for a long time. In case the size of the files is getting in the way they are 33347 kb, 123665 kb, and 178688 kb respectfully though I doubt this is the case because the last two are similar in size.

```
// a property in a class
private HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; } = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1) };

// in a function in that class
using Stream stationsStream = await HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://eddb.io/archive/v6/stations.jsonl");
using Stream systemsStream = await HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://eddb.io/archive/v6/systems_populated.jsonl");
// always gets stuck on the third await no matter the order.
using Stream listingStream = await HttpClient.GetStreamAsync("https://eddb.io/archive/v6/listings.csv");
```

I haven't used the HttpClient class too much but some theories that came up are that the API only allows two connections or the HttpClient only can take two.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328958/5045688

Comment: Are you thinking to actually read anything from those streams at any point?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I have 3 async tasks that need to read data from the streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create the `HttpClient` with a `HttpClientHandler` and pass the `HttpClientHandler` into the `HttpClient`'s constructor also changing the `HttpClientHandler`'s `MaxConnectionsPerServer` to a larger number. For example:

```
private HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; } = new HttpClient(Handler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1) };
private static HttpClientHandler Handler { get; set; } = new HttpClientHandler() { MaxConnectionsPerServer = 3 };
```