# Multiple HttpClients with proxies, trying to achieve maximum download speed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, web-scraping, httpclient, tpl-dataflow

I need to use proxies to download a forum. The problem with my code is that it takes only 10% of my internet bandwidth. Also I have read that I need to use a single `HttpClient` instance, but with multiple proxies I don't know how to do it. Changing `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` doesn't change anything.

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<IFetchResult> FetchInParallelAsync(
    this IEnumerable<Url> urls, FetchContext context)
{
    var fetchBlcock = new TransformBlock<Url, IFetchResult>(
        transform: url => url.FetchAsync(context), 
        dataflowBlockOptions: new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions 
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 128
        }
    );
    foreach(var url in urls)
        fetchBlcock.Post(url);

    fetchBlcock.Complete();
    var result = fetchBlcock.ToAsyncEnumerable();
    return result;
}
```

Every call to `FetchAsync` will create or reuse a `HttpClient` with a `WebProxy`.

```
public static async Task<IFetchResult> FetchAsync(this Url url, FetchContext context)
{
    var httpClient = context.ProxyPool.Rent();
    var result = await url.FetchAsync(httpClient, context.Observer, context.Delay,
        context.isReloadWithCookie);
    context.ProxyPool.Return(httpClient);
    return result;
}

public HttpClient Rent() 
{
    lock(_lockObject)
    {
        if (_uninitiliazedDatacenterProxiesAddresses.Count != 0)
        {
            var proxyAddress = _uninitiliazedDatacenterProxiesAddresses.Pop();
            return proxyAddress.GetWebProxy(DataCenterProxiesCredentials).GetHttpClient();
        }
        return _proxiesQueue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

I am a novice at software developing, but the task of downloading using hundreds or thousands of proxies asynchronously looks like a trivial task that many should have been faced with and found a correct way to do it. So far I was unable to find any solutions to my problem on the internet. Any thoughts of how to achieve maximum download speed?

Comment: Take a look at this: [What is HttpClient's default maximum connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735569/what-is-httpclients-default-maximum-connections)

Comment: `.ConfigureAwait(false);` check if this helps add to end of `await url.FetchAsync(httpClient, context.Observer, context.Delay,
        context.isReloadWithCookie);`

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what happens here:

```
var result = await url.FetchAsync(httpClient, context.Observer, context.Delay, context.isReloadWithCookie);
```

You are actually `await`**ing** before you continue with the next item. That's why it is asynchronous and not parallel programming. [async in Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

> The await keyword is where the magic happens. It yields control to the caller of the method that performed await, and it ultimately allows a UI to be responsive or a service to be elastic.

In essence, it frees the calling thread to do other stuff **but** the original calling code is suspended from executing, until the IO operation is done.

Now to your problem:

1. You can either use this excellent solution here: [foreach async](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync/)
2. You can use the Parallel library to execute your code in different threads.

Something like the following from [Parallel for example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netcore-3.1)

```
Parallel.For(0, urls.Count,
         index => fetchBlcock.Post(urls[index])
});
```

Comment: Athanasios `Post`ing to a dataflow block is practically instantaneous. There is no need to parallelize it with `Parallel.For`.

Comment: I based my answer on this mostly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Dataflow_DataflowBlock_Post__1_System_Threading_Tasks_Dataflow_ITargetBlock___0____0_  `For target blocks that support postponing offered messages, or for blocks that may do more processing in their Post implementation, consider using SendAsync, which will return immediately` infering that it is not instantaneous. I'm not really an expert on Dataflows though, so it's just a suggestion.

Comment: The `Post` method returns immediately, and the return value indicates whether the message was accepted or not. The `SendAsync` method also returns immediately, and the return value is a `Task<bool>` that completes when the dataflow block has definitely accepted or rejected the message. The difference between the two is in case of postponement. The `Post` interprets a `Postponed` response as not-accepted, while the `SendAsync` interprets it as a promise that may fulfilled later and returns an incomplete task. In practice you need to use `SendAsync` with blocks configured with `BoundedCapacity`.