# How can I Post data using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I have this `HttpWebRequest`:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/api/Phrase/GetJDTO");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
```

But I need to add a payload to the body of the request like this:

```
Jlpt = 2
```

Can someone help and tell me how I can add data to the POST ?

Comment: If you can, use `HttpClient` rather than `HttpWebRequest`. It has a more modern, asynchronous API, and a much more straightforward way to add a payload to a request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do by this

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://example.com/api/Phrase/GetJDTO");

var postData = "Jlpt = 2";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

but I suggest you use `HttpClient` rather than `HttpWebRequest` in this case

Comment: Thanks very much.  Can you explain why you suggest to use HttpClient? What's the difference? Thank you.

Comment: you can find more detail in this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214930/httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 2):

```
if (data != null)
{
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        stream.Write(serialized);
    }
}
else
{
    request.ContentLength = 0;
}
```

where data is any object you want to send