# How can I load cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, cross-browser, cross-domain

How can I load cross domain HTML page with jQuery AJAX?

Suppose I want to get a page outside my domain using jQuery AJAX:

```
$.get('http://www.domain.com/mypage.html', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

I will probably get this error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com/path/filename. Origin
>   null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

we can't load cross domain page using AJAX because of the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

I could try using 'jsonp' to bypass this restriction:

```
$.ajax({
  type:     "GET",
  url:      url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

But what if 'jsonp' is not supported in this site? this could be a problem.

What if I just want to read an external page and parse its HTML?

Comment: Do you have control over the "outside" domain? I ask because if so, look into CORS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17299796/612253

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is an old post. But, I hope this will help someone else who is looking for the same.*

**Simply you can't.** - same-origin policy or you need to set CORS headers for `www.domain.com`

But, If you just want to fetch an external page content to your page, there is a workaround you could do:

**Create an endpoint in your server to return the HTML content for the given external URL.** (because you can't get external content to the browser - *same-origin policy*)

**JS:**

```
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent('http://www.domain.com/mypage.html');
$.get('http://www.yourdomain.com/getcontent?url=' + encodedUrl, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

**[Easiest way to read from a URL into a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048204/826611) - *may use this to create `/getcontent` endpoint***

Answer (score -3):

You can use '[AJAX Cross Origin](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/)' a jQuery plugin to load cross domain HTML page. 
AJAX Cross Origin is a jQuery plugin to allow Cross Origin AJAX requests.
With this plugin we can easily bypass the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and do cross domain requests.

It is very simple to use:

```
   $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: true,
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/