# C# Create a variable that is a web document

Tags: c#, web

I have a text document saved onto my website. What I would like to do, is create a variable in my C# program that is equal to the contents of that text document. Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file

Comment: @Bigbob556677 This doesn't use System.net atall. Im looking to read a text document off of a website

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1048199/8521346

Comment: @Bigbob556677 I dont think so, but ill try