# Passing JavaScript string from web page to C# Winforms?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webview, cefsharp

I have a web page embedded into `CefSharp webview`.
That web page is using a `setInterval` JS function to check if there is a new message into the database every `XX` seconds.

Is there a way to make a `C# Winforms` notification once the web page have found a new message?

Comment: I am not familiar with `CefSharp` but look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048199/easiest-way-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-string-in-net) and [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html) maybe it helps you

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript