# C# JSON URL get data

Tags: c#, json, parsing, get, set

Im new to System.Net with C#
I want a way to get info from this website api: https://fn-api.glitch.me/api/aes
from its json to a C# string

I have this so far

I don't know how to get each item and where to put the url (im really new to this).

I want the url in a string:

```
public class Data
{
    public string build { get; set; }
    public string netCL { get; set; }
    public string manifestID { get; set; }
    public string aes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "I want the url in a string" : `string url = "https://fn-api.glitch.me/api/aes";`. Maybe you want to get the content of the page ? Take a look at [System.Net.WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8)(You didn't say if you are on .net core or .net full framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is how you get about it. I am showing you an example using `HttpClient` to first read the content from the API and then de-serialize it using `Newtonsoft` package.

HttpClient class:

```
public class HttpClientFactory
{
  private string webServiceUrl = "https://fn-api.glitch.me/";

  public HttpClient CreateClient()
  {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    SetupClientDefaults(client);
    return client;
  }

  protected virtual void SetupClientDefaults(HttpClient client)
  {
    //This is global for all REST web service calls
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webServiceUrl);
  }
}
```

Your Model class:

```
public class Data
{
  public string build { get; set; }
  public string netCL { get; set; }
  public string manifestID { get; set; }
  public string aes { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can call this class and create an instance of the `HttpClient` like this:

```
public RootObject InvokeAPI()
{
  RootObject apiresponse = new RootObject();
  string result = string.Empty;
  HttpClientFactory clientFactory = new HttpClientFactory();
  var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/aes").Result;
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    apiresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
  }
 return apiresponse;
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

EDIT:

As per your code, you need to call the `API` on your `Button` click:

```
    private void metroButton2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //You need to invoke the API method !!!!
        var apiresponse=InvokeAPI();
        metroTextBox1.Text = apiresponse.data.aes;
    }
```

Be sure to put `try-catch` blocks on your code for error handling.

Comment: This may be a silly question but how do I GET the aes?
Like if I wanted to do this: `metroTextBox1.Text = ???;`

Comment: @ProMasterBoy-Gaming Once you get the de-serialized object, you can do: `metroTextBox1.Text=apiresponse.data.aes;`

Comment: @ProMasterBoy-Gaming You are de-serializing the string here: `apiresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);` where apiresponse is of type `RootObject` from your `Model`

Comment: Where would I put the `apiresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);`?

Comment: @ProMasterBoy-Gaming I am not quite sure about that since I do not have your code structure here. You would need to put this where you are calling the `API` via `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a 3rd party library like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It'll give you a client that's easy to work with and does the converting into objects automatically.

Alternatively you could use the [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) and download the JSON. Using something like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) allows you to deserialize the JSON into an object.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Easiest way to read from a URL into a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048199/easiest-way-to-read-from-a-url-into-a-string-in-net)
2. I use [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: Please explain further (im only 13 xD)